# How to simulate typing in input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, keyboard-events, textinput

What I want is to simulate typing in `<input>` field using javascript.

I have the following code:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keydown");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 65;
$("#test").trigger(press);
```

But when I load the page, the `#test` input field has no typed characters,  the keycode of '65' represents 'A', but there is no 'A' input.

Basically what I want is to automatically typing in the website using Greasemonkey.

Please give me some ideas or some library with which I can use to do this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 56):

You can send key events, and anything listening for them will get them, **but they will not change the input**, so you will not see the letter `A` appear, for example.  This is mostly a security thing; see ["Manually firing events"](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents#domevld1) for a discussion about that.

So, if you want the letter to appear, you must alter the input's value as you send the key event.  There is a jQuery plugin for that, see ["The `$.fn.sendkeys` Plugin"](http://bililite.com/blog/2011/01/23/improved-sendkeys/).

You can see how an `<input>` reacts with user-applied keys, key events, and that plugin at [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DxER9/).

For reference, this is the key piece of code from that jsFiddle:

```
$("button").click ( function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.target.id == "simA_plain") {
        console.log ("Send Plain key event");
        var keyVal = 65;
        $("#eventTarg").trigger ( {
            type: 'keypress', keyCode: keyVal, which: keyVal, charCode: keyVal
        } );
    }
    else {
        console.log ("Use the Plugin to simulate a keystroke");
        $("#eventTarg").sendkeys ("B") ;
    }
} );
```

---

---

That plugin should be sufficient if you are just trying to "simulate typing on an `<input>`".  However, depending on what you are *really* trying to do, you may need to do one or more of the following:

1. Just set the text to what you want it to be.
2. Send a `keydown` event, if the page's javascript triggers off of that.
3. Likewise, send a `change` event, etc., if the page's javascript triggers off of that.
4. Just find and call the page's javascript directly.  Use *script injection*, the *location hack*, `unsafeWindow`, and/or `@grant none` mode to do that.
5. Something else?  State your true objective and link to the target page.

Comment: it really helpful :)

Comment: @isa, I just checked the link and the Fiddle. Both seem to still function. Why/how *exactly* does it "not work"?

Comment: Oh, I guess it's my problem perhaps, but I don't know why. It brought me to the fiddle page and it the cloud icon just kept jumping forever and contents don't seem to load.

Comment: @isa, that's a question for a different site. But it's probably your browser, or its config, or its extensions. Or, might be the network you're on.

Comment: what is the Javascript only equivalent of this please? I'm trying to manually simulate a typed search on a third party website within a Chrome extension and can't figure out how to trigger their search code as the manual type and search behaves differently than the programmatic one....