# Can I modify the contents of a jQuery event in a userscript?

Tags: jquery, userscripts

I want to modify the contents of `event` objects in a userscript.

Specifically, I want to do this simple operation:

```
if (event.metaKey) event.ctrlKey = true;
```

i.e., If my script is running on a page that uses jQuery, events that are used by that instance of jQuery will register a <kbd>cmd</kbd> key press as a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key press.

Is what I'm thinking of even possible? If so, how can I redefine how jQuery creates event objects[?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219982/150214)

Comment: You may be able to use the hotkeys plugin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593602/keyboard-shortcuts-with-jquery

Comment: If the event listeners are jQuery-based, you should be able to capture and retrigger.  You will need to inject the code that does this.  Beware that many (¿most?) [native event handlers ignore artificial key events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13946504/331508).